# Why in the russian often used "все точки над И" but not "все точки над Ё"?

Tags: грамматика, буква-ё

Why is this in use: "все точки над И"? There is no dots - **И**, there is dot in English version **i**.

Why instead there is no usage for such construction:

- все точки над Ё

or

- все бреве над И краткое

?

Comment: *Расставить точки над ё* is quite a popular phrase as well: http://goo.gl/pl6owQ

Comment: Диакритический знак в "и краткое" называется "кратка" или "бреве", а не тире. Так, к слову.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a historical phrase. Before 1918 there were two kinds of letter и - **и** and **і**. At that time ink was used to write and dots over i were put after all the letters in the word is written completely. The meaning of the phrase is "to do the things until every little thing is in place".

Letter **ё** on the other hand is optional. Most writers do not put the dots over it. So, the meaning of the phrase changes to "to do even the things nobody cares about". Actually I've met the phrase "все точки над Ё", but it causes an obviously humorous effect.

As for letter **й** - the thingy over и is called "кратка", so the right "proverb" would be "Поставить все кратки над и кратким", which sounds too repetitious and nobody knows the term anyway.

Also the letter **i** happend more often than **ё** and **й** and so the saying sounded most logical at the time it become popular.

I think that this phrase could be borrowed from other language, for instance in English there is a saying ["to dot the i's and cross the t's"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dot_the_i%27s_and_cross_the_t%27s). (UPD: user3711 claims that the proverb came from French language, which is quite likely).

---

Интересно что по-французски пословица звучит как "mettre les points sur les i". [Здесь](http://www.nikibar.com/news/mots-bizarres-expressions-curieuses.html) дается такое объяснение (перевод на основе Google Translate):

> В средние века монахи-переписчики экономили пергамент, поэтому готические буквы были очень плотными и краткими. В результате букву `I` можно было спутать с буквой `l`. Чтобы различать их, над буквой I стали ставить точку. Позже точку стали ставить и над буквой J.   Выражение означает: дать все подробности, объяснить все четко и твердо с кем-то кто не понимает или не хочет понять.

Возможно что английское "dot the i's and cross the t's" возникло на основе французской поговорки - перечеркивание буквы t не упоминается ни в русской ни во французской версии. И, кстати, это перечеркивание t указывает на переосмысливание выражения - уже нет отсылки к средневековым монахам-переписчикам, а имеется в виду сам процесс перечеркивания вертикальных линий в букве t и проставления точек над i и j после того как написано слово целиком при каллиграфическом письме.

American Heritage Dictionary [дает примеры английского выражения](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dot+the+i%27s+and+cross+the+t%27s?s=t) середины 19 века. Кроме того Google Ngram Viewer находит французское выражение [начиная с 1750 года](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=points%20sur%20les%20i&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4;,points%20sur%20les%20i;,c0;,s0;;points%20sur%20les%20i;,c0;;points%20sur%20les%20I;,c0), а английское - [начиная с 1840 года](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dot%20the%20i%27s&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4;,dot%20the%20i%20%27s;,c0;,s0;;dot%20the%20i%20%27s;,c0;;dot%20the%20I%20%27s;,c0;;Dot%20the%20i%20%27s;,c0).

Что касается русского языка, то князь П. А. Вяземский пишет:

> В исторических и анекдотических рассказах должно, сколько есть возможности, по французской поговорке, ставить les points sur les i [точки над i]: то есть всякое лыко в строку. [П. А. Вяземский. Старая записная книжка (1830-1870)]

Еще один пример из Национального корпуса:

> Но он терпел полнейшее фиаско, когда дело шло о различных «обличениях», где уже приходилось волей-неволей говорить прямо и ставить точки над «и», как говорят французы. [А.К. Шеллер-Михайлов. Лес рубят - щепки летят (1871)]

Как видим, оба автора прямо указывают на французское происхождение поговорки.

Answer (score 6):

This proverb is an adaptation of French "mettre les points sur les i et les barres sur les t". Before the reform of Russian orthography in 1918 there was a letter "i" in Russian alphabet ("и десятеричное", it presents in contemporary Ukrainian alphabet, for example), but there was no "t". So the original French proverb was reduced.

Answer (score 2):

When Russians use that proverb they mean not the cyrillic letter `И`, but latin or old cyrillic `i`. The reason may lie in the fact that letter `Ё` is very often being used without dots, like `Е`. **UPD**: Artemix led more compelling reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно так: "Все точки над i"

Латинская буква i имеется ввиду.

Comment: Нет, не латинская - русская. Когда появилась эта пословица в русском языке была буква і. Пословица не стала бы популярной если бы не имела практического смысла. Вот вы часто расставляете точки над латинскими буквами i?

Comment: @Artemix я не совсем понял вашу позицию, как вы сами и написали выше - и правильно написали, это французское выражение - http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mettre_les_points_sur_les_i - оно проникло через франкофонную российскую элиту - так что действительно подразумевалось изначально латинская i.

Comment: @shabunc Я считаю, что пословица была актуальной и со временем стала восприниматься как русская именно потому что в русском языке тоже была буква і. Пока в орфографии была буква і постановка вопроса "имеется в виду французская і или русская і?" была бы странной. Ответ скорее всего такой: "буква і, которую я пишу каждый день".

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to other answers: letter "ё" was added to russian alphabet at the end of XVIII century, so probably this expression existed earlier than letter "ё".

Comment: Скорее всего ё не упоминается т.к. само выражение заимствовано из французского языка. Вяземский пишет в середине 19 века: "В исторических и анекдотических рассказах должно, сколько есть возможности, по французской поговорке, ставить les points sur les i [точки над i]: то есть всякое лыко в строку. [П. А. Вяземский. Старая записная книжка (1830-1870)]".